# I have lost wordpress password. in database it has been encrypted in user table. how to get back password?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Wordpress : How to get back wordpress password(test), where wordpress has been encrypted? is there a way to view my password without resetting, forget password?

Comment: WordPress has an [extensive tutorial on how to reset your password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Resetting_Your_Password). This kind of question is off topic on SO as it has absolutely no relation to programming.

Answer (score 2):

open your `table` in `database` and edit that user and `create` new password for it using `MD5 Function`

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i don't have permission to access database. just i have wordpress files or project. so how can i change or get back to wp-admin access. still i am blinking....

Answer (score 0):

You can't get back the password, But you can use `MD5` to put your new password into `users` table of your Wordpress database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i don't have permission to access database. just i have wordpress files or project. so how can i change or get back to wp-admin access. still i am blinking....